# E0144 значение типа "const char *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char *"

Tags: c++, файлы

Я в С++ не очень (очень не) разбираюсь, поэтому помогите, пожалуйста. Пишет ошибку в строке 59     `char* name = "myfile.txt";` . Почему и как исправить?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void create_file(char* name)
{
    char s[100]; FILE* f;
    f = fopen(name, "wt"); //открыть файл для создания как текстовый
    if (f == NULL) { cout << "Cannot create file\n"; return; }//проверить, открылся ли файл
        cout << "Input strings" << endl;
    do { //цикл пока не введена пустая строка
        gets_s(s, 100); //ввести строку с клавиатуры
        fputs(s, f); //записать её в файл
        fputs("\n", f); // если не добавить перевод на новую строку, то все строки сольются в одну
    } while (strcmp(s, ""));
        fclose(f); //закрыть файл (он при этом сохранится)
}

    void view_file(char* name)
{
    char s[100]; FILE* f;
    f = fopen(name, "rt"); //открыть файл для чтения как текстовый
    if (f == NULL) { cout << "Cannot open file to view\n"; return; }
    cout << "\nView file" << endl;
    while (fgets(s, 100, f)) { //считывать из файла строки, пока они не закончатся (пока не достигнут конец файла)

        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0'; //без этой строки строки будут выводиться через пустую строку из-за добавленного ранее '\n'

        puts(s); //вывести строку на экран
    }
    fclose(f);
}

    int kol_znakov(char* name)
    {
        char s[100]; FILE* f;
        int kol = 0; //переменная для количества знаков препинания в файле
        f = fopen(name, "rt");
        if (f == NULL) { cout << "Cannot open file\n"; return 0; }
        while (fgets(s, 100, f)) {
            if (ispunct(*s))
            {
                kol++;
            }

        }
        fclose(f);
            return kol;
    }


int main()
{
    FILE * f = NULL; //объявление файловой переменной (локальной)
    char* name = "myfile.txt"; //имя файла на жёстком диске (в текущей папке проекта)
    create_file(name); //вызов функции создания файла. Её можно один раз выполнить, а потом закомментировать
    view_file(name); //вызов функции просмотра файла дальнейшие функции базируются на функции просмотра файла:
    cout << "\nKolichestvo znakov v texte: " << kol_znakov(name);//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в строке `char* name = "myfile.txt";`
Такие строки времени компиляции помещаются в память, доступную только для чтения и имеют тип `const char [N]`, где N длина литерала + нуль-символ. Им можно инициализировать массив `char name[] = "myfile.txt"`, размер массива будет вычислен автоматически, const необязателен, литерал будет скопирован в массив, но если добавить, то придётся добавлять const во все параметры функций. Или 
инициализировать указатель `const char * name = "myfile.txt"`, тут const обязателен, так как указатель будет ссылаться на оригинальную(защищённую от записи) строку. Соответственно, вам нужно `char * name` переделать в `char name[]`, либо в `const char * name` в main и во всех параметрах функций.